# Sending SMS via AT+CMGS command programatically

Tags: c, gsm, at-command, tty

I'm trying to send SMS via MC7304 modem programatically in C++. For AT command, linux share /dev/ttyUSB1 port. Here is my code:

```
fd_set readSet, writeSet;
struct timeval timeval;

int cellFd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR, 0);
writeSet = readSet;

timeval.tv_sec = 0;
timeval.tv_usec = 3000000;

int n = 0;

int written = 0;
int readed = 0;
int totalRead = 0;

char buffer[1001];
memset(buffer, '\0', 1001);



written = write(cellFd, "AT+CMGF=1\r\n", 11);
printf("AT+CMGF=1 command sent with result: %d. Waiting for response...\n", written);


while(true)
{
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(cellFd, &readSet);

timeval.tv_sec = 2;
timeval.tv_usec = 0;

n = select(cellFd + 1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, &timeval);

if(n == 0)
{
  break;
}
else if(n > 0)
{     
  readed = read(cellFd, buffer + totalRead, 1000 - totalRead);

  totalRead += readed;
}
else
{
  printf("Error\n");
  exit(0);
}
}


if(totalRead > 0)
{
  cout << buffer << endl;
}
else
{
  printf("No data received\n");
}

totalRead = 0;
readed = 0;
memset(buffer, '\0', 1001);







written = write(cellFd, "AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"\r\n", 15);
printf("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\" command sent with result: %d. Waiting for response...\n", written);

while(true)
{
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(cellFd, &readSet);

timeval.tv_sec = 2;
timeval.tv_usec = 0;

n = select(cellFd + 1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, &timeval);

if(n == 0)
{
  break;
}
else if(n > 0)
{     
  readed = read(cellFd, buffer + totalRead, 1000 - totalRead);

  totalRead += readed;
}
else
{
  printf("Error\n");
  exit(0);
}
}


if(totalRead > 0)
{
  cout << buffer << endl;
}
else
{
  printf("No data received\n");
}

totalRead = 0;
readed = 0;
memset(buffer, '\0', 1001);











written = write(cellFd, "AT+CMGS=\"MY_NUMBER\"\r\n", 24);
printf("AT+CMGS=\"+MY_NUMBER\" command sent with %d result. Waiting for response...\n", written);

while(true)
{
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(cellFd, &readSet);

timeval.tv_sec = 3;
timeval.tv_usec = 0;

n = select(cellFd + 1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, &timeval);

if(n == 0)
{
  printf("No data\n");
  break;
}
else if(n > 0)
{     
  memset(buffer, '\0', 1001);
  readed = read(cellFd, buffer, 1000);

  for(int i=0; i<readed; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  cout << buffer << endl;

  if((*(buffer) == 0x3E) && (*(buffer + 1) == 0x20) && (*(buffer + 2) == 0x0A))
  {
    written = write(cellFd, "Test\x1A", 5);
    printf("SMS text sent with %d result. Waiting for response...\n", written);
  }
}
else
{
  printf("Error\n");
  exit(0);
}
}
```

The first two commands work fine and returning 'OK' response. Unfortunetly, after sending AT+CMGS command, modem response with 0x0A (line feed) twice, next responsing with 0x3E 0x20 0x0A (> ) (that looks ok). After this sequence, i'm sending text that ends with 0x1A (CTRL-Z), but modem still responding with >. This situation repeats hundreds of times and at the end I got error +CMS ERROR: 305. It looks like:

```
root@Moxa:/home/SMS# ./SMS
AT+CMGF=1 command sent with result: 11. Waiting for response...
OK
AT+CSCS="GSM" command sent with result: 15. Waiting for response...
OK
AT+CMGS="(SOME NUMBER)" command sent with 24 result. Waiting for response...
>
SMS text sent with 5 result. Waiting for response...
>
[ situation repeats ]
SMS text sent with 5 result. Waiting for response...
+CMS ERROR: 305
```

What's wrong with this code, how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code `written = write(cellFd, "AT+CMGS=\"MY_NUMBER\"\r\n", 24);` doesn't appear to append the control-z.  The > means that it is waiting for the end of the message.  Are you sure you are sending a control-z?  Why isn't it in the code you posted?

Comment: This line: `written = write(cellFd, "Test\x1A", 5);` contains control-z (0x1A at the end). All tutorials say that control-z should be sent after text, not after command.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that.  My apologies.

Comment: There's a lot of code duplication there. ANd the formatting doesn't make it easy to read either.

Comment: It's just a draft code, two first commands are not so important so you can start reading from line `written = write(cellFd, "AT+CMGS=\"MY_NUMBER\"\r\n", 24);`. ;)